# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established(while trying to connect DocumentDB using Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am working on a requirement where I am using AWS DocumentDB as database and using NodeJS as programming language in backend application and deploying the setup on AWS ECS Fargate.
When I configure backend APIs in front end app and executes the backend APIs then it works for initial few calls and then after sometime i get error message as below.(FYI - I have whitelisted the container security group of my backend application in DocumentDB cluster's security group.)

{
"message": "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
"stack": "Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established\n    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:607:14)\n    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1544:19)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)\n    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)\n    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)",
"name": "MongoNetworkError"
}

Any idea on it's resolution?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand this right that the errors are transient in nature? Is there something that might be triggering these errors?